# Creating a rect grid in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I need to create a clickable 8 by 8 grid in pygame.
Right now I have something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Imports & Inits
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Settings
WIDTH = 105
HEIGHT = 105
FPS = 60
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Screen Setup
WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode([WIDTH,HEIGHT])
CAPTION = pygame.display.set_caption('Test')
SCREEN = pygame.display.get_surface()
TRANSPARENT = pygame.Surface([WIDTH,HEIGHT])
TRANSPARENT.set_alpha(255)
TRANSPARENT.fill((255,255,255))
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Misc stuff
rect1 = pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, (255, 255, 255), (0,0, 50, 50))
rect2 = pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, (255, 255, 255), (0,55, 50, 50))
rect3 = pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, (255, 255, 255), (55,0, 50, 50))
rect4 = pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, (255, 255, 255), (55,55, 50, 50))

...

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Refresh Display
pygame.display.flip()
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Main Loop
while True: 
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    mouse = pygame.draw.circle(TRANSPARENT, (0, 0, 0), pos , 0)
    # Event Detection---------------
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == QUIT: 
            sys.exit() 
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if rect1.contains(mouse):
                rect1 = pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, (155, 155, 155), (0,0, 50, 50))
                pygame.display.flip()
```

Now, in my original code, I have far more rectangles and I need a way to do something like this:

```
for i in rectangles:
    if i hasbeenclickedon:
          change color
```

Obviously, my solution is far too static.
So, how could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though your solution is indeed a little cumbersome, I'd first say

```
rectangles = (rect1, rect2, ...)
```

then you can iterate over them as intended.

Try sth like

```
pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
for rect in rectangles:
    if rect.collidepoint(pos):
        changecolor(rect)
```

You'd have to implement the `changecolor` method, of course.

Generally, I'd recommend creating a class for you clickable fields that defines a method `changecolor`.

Comment: Haha, now that you pointed it out, it is so obvious.
Thank you very much. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Btw. now that I see that you're actually drawing 64 rectangles, I'd strongly recommend drawing them with a loop and adding them to the `rectangles` list simultaneously.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped and you don't expect any more helpful answers. ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Simple 'human' colors:

```
Color("red")
Color(255,255,255)
Color("#fefefe")
```

## Use:

```
import pygame
# This makes event handling, rect, and colors simpler.
# Now you can refer to `Sprite` or `Rect()` vs `pygame.sprite.Sprite` or `pygame.Rect()`
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame import Color, Rect, Surface

pygame.draw.rect(screen, Color("blue"), Rect(10,10,200,200), width=0)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, Color("darkred"), Rect(210,210,400,400), width=0)
```